# Equivalent of this htaccess for IIS7?

Tags: apache, iis, zend-framework, .htaccess, iis-7

What is the equivalent of these rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

In IIS7?

These are rewrite rules for Zend Framework and they work under Apache. I tried importing them into IIS7 with the URL rewrite module but the import fails (there are two errors).

Could anybody help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had never use ZF with IIS but i guess that would help you

http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV/Configuring+Your+URL+Rewriter

or

http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/zend-framework-url-rewriting-in-iis6/

or

http://iirf.codeplex.com/

also Rob allen had very nice article  "Zend Framework URLs without mod_rewrite"

http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/zend-framework-urls-without-mod_rewrite/